# comparing a cell with all other ones in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, comparison, conditional-formatting

i would like to know the answer for this problem:

i want to compare a cell from column A (for example A1) with all other cells in column A and if there is a duplicate, then compare the adjacent cell (B1) with the adjacent cell found as duplicate. If the two cells are duplicate return true or format it red and if not return false or remain the original format.

for example:

```
MIKE      CARIE
ALBERT    WILL
SARAH     JULIE
MIKE      ALLISON
SARAH     JULIE
```

i mean that this formula should format the "sarah julie" red or returns as true
and
should do nothing with "mike carie" and "mike allison"

i wanted to use formula in conditional formatting but i was not able to succeed.

Answer (score 2):

### Conditional Formatting: Two-Column Duplicates

- If the data is in `A2:B6`, **select this range** before you use

  ```
  =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$6,$A2,$B$2:$B$6,$B2)>1
  ```

  in *Conditional Formatting* or use it in e.g. cell `C2` and copy down.
- Obviously, you can do this for as many columns as necessary.

[image]

- Since the '`IF` family' of functions does not work with arrays, you can achieve the same with `SUM` when dealing with arrays, and `COUNTIFS` is not an option:

  ```
  =SUM(($A$2:$A$6=$A2)*($B$2:$B$6=$B2))>1
  ```
- If you don't have MS365, you can use `SUMPRODUCT` instead:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$6=$A2)*($B$2:$B$6=$B2))>1
  ```

Comment: thank you so much, but it seems to do nothing with conditional formatting.

Comment: is it neccesary to  add formula in cell and then add the formula to conditional formatting?

Comment: No, it just shows `TRUE` for the rows that will be highlighted. It's kind of a way to build the formula. Maybe you forgot to pick a fill color?

Comment: 1.) Copy the formula-->2.) Select the whole range-->Ribbon-->Home-->Styles-->Conditional Formatting-->New Rule-->Use a formula to determine which cells to format-->3.) Paste the formula-->Format-->Fill-->4.) Select a color-->Ok-->Ok.

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNTIFS()`.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1)>1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

[image]

For conditional formatting, try-

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,$B1)>1
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, but it seems to do nothing with conditional formatting

Comment: is it neccesary to  add formula in cell and then add the formula to conditional formatting?

Comment: @zahrasoleimani No, no need necessary to put formula in cells. You can directly put the formula to conditional formatting rule.